# duplicate values to be shown as null in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm new to sql servers, I have a table as follows

```
   **Emp_name     |  year  |  rank **
    emp1             2010       1
    emp1             2011       2
    emp1             2012       3
    emp2             2012       1
    emp2             2013       2
    emp3             2009       3
    emp2             2010       4
    emp3             2011       5
```

Emp_name column has duplicate values, I want a query that will return following result,

```
**Emp_name     |  year  |  rank **
 emp1             2010       1
 null (emp1)      2011       2
 null (emp1)      2012       3
 emp2             2012       1
 null (emp2)      2013       2
 emp3             2009       3
 null (emp2)      2010       4
 null (emp3)      2011       5
```

Only 1 of the values from the duplicate values(Emp_name column should be seen and the rest as null or as a blank space.

Comment: Your output result is not clear,can you make it bit clearer?

Comment: i don't think that's possible. where will you use this data? maybe we can suggest code-part actions you can make.

Comment: @AnandPhadke there's an mistype in emp3, I guess. he wants to get emp_name only where rank is 1 and null or empty string  otherwise, as I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Emp_name varchar(4), year int, rank int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (Emp_name, year, rank)
VALUES
    ('emp1', 2010, 1),
    ('emp1', 2011, 2),
    ('emp1', 2012, 3),
    ('emp2', 2012, 1),
    ('emp2', 2013, 2),
    ('emp3', 2009, 3),
    ('emp2', 2010, 4),
    ('emp3', 2011, 5)
;

select 
CASE WHEN rn=1 then EMP_NAME else null end EMP_NAME,
year,rank
from 
(
  select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_name order by (select 0)) as rn from Table1
) a
```